# Get first value that is not nil in a model full of custom objects

Tags: swift, model, sequence, mirror

So I have this model:

```
public class Loot {

    let sword: Sword?
    let armor: Armor?

    init(sword: Sword? = nil, armor: Armor? = Armor()) {
        self.sword = sword
        self.armor = armor
    }
}
```

All of these attributes inherit from an `Item` class.

In this model i will always only have 1 of the attributes not nil. Are there any way i can fetch this?

Using this one:

```
extension Sequence where Element == Loot {

        var items: [Item] {
            var internaltems: [Item] = []
            for loot in self {
                let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: loot)
                let item = mirror.children.first { (label, value) -> Bool in
                    let internalValue = value as? Item
                    return internalValue != nil
                }
                if let item = item {
                    internaltems.append(item.value as! Item)
                }
            }
            return internaltems
        }
}
```

I can get the first object that is not nil and the `Item` base for it. printing this out in the prompt with `po loots.items` i can actually see that it is an `Armor` object. But it's still an `Item` object so i can't reach the Armor attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of holding two properties of which only one is set you can have a generic class with only one mandatory property. This way you won't have to check what is or isn't set

```
class Loot<T: Item> {
    let item: T

    init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
    }
}
```

Example

```
let loot1 = Loot(item: Armor())
let loot2 = Loot(item: Sword())
```

If you want to access the item as an `Armor` or `Sword` I would suggest adding computed properties in an extension. It's better to add them in an extension since this isn't part of the core functionality of the class and it is also a better design if you create another type of `Item` like `Shield` then you can add a computed property for it in an extension without having to modify the main class.

```
extension Loot {
    var armor: Armor? {
        get {
            guard let armor = item as? Armor else {return nil}
            return armor
        }
    }

    var sword: Sword? {
        get {
            guard let sword = item as? Sword else {return nil}
            return sword
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access them as optionals

```
if let armor = loot1.armor {
    //do armor stuff
}
```

Comment: It's a nice way of doing it, making it a lot cleaner. But stil then the object is an `Item` and i can't reach the `Armor` or `Sword` properties?

Comment: I gave you upvote for the clean structure. However, i figured i had to put an enum type inside the Item to declare the type of the Item and then unwrap it with a switch